# read in numbered files in right order

Tags: perl

I have 1500 files in one directory and I need to get some information out of every one and write it into a new, single file. The file names consist of a word and a number (Temp1, Temp2, Temp3 and so on) and it is important that the files are read in the correct order according to the numbers.
I did this using

```
my @files = <Temp*.csv>;

for my $file (@files) 
    { 
       this part appends the required data to a seperate file and works fine
    }
```

my problem now is that the files are not opened in the correct order but after file 1 the file 100 gets opened.
Can anybody please give me a hint how I can make it read the files in the right order?

Thank you,
Ca

Answer (score 4):

Sort the files naturally with [`Sort::Key::Natural natsort`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural).

The following will automatically sort the files naturally, separating out alpha and numerical portions of the name for the appropriate sort logic.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Sort::Key::Natural qw(natsort);

for my $file ( natsort <Temp*.csv> ) {
    # this part appends the required data to a seperate file and works fine
}
```

The following fake data should demonstrate this module in action:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Sort::Key::Natural qw(natsort);

print natsort <DATA>;

__DATA__
Temp100.csv
Temp8.csv
Temp20.csv
Temp1.csv
Temp7.csv
```

Outputs:

```
Temp1.csv
Temp7.csv
Temp8.csv
Temp20.csv
Temp100.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to read and sort files in one step,

```
my @files = 
  map { $_->[0] }
  sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
  map { [ $_, /(\d+)/ ] } <Temp*.csv>;
```

or using less efficient, and more straightforward sort,

```
my @files = sort { ($a =~ /(\d+)/)[0] <=> ($b =~ /(\d+)/)[0] } <Temp*.csv>;
```

Comment: Or without ST: `my @files = sort { ($a =~ /(\d+)/)[0] <=> ($b =~ /(\d+)/)[0] } <Temp*.csv>;` Slower over long lists, but for typical uses, you won't notice the difference.

Comment: Schwartzian Transform is an optimisation, and shouldn't be used until the code has been written and tested, found to be too slow, and profiled to find that the sort is a bottleneck. Your version without a transform unnecessarily confines itself to a single expression, and is far from clear. The obvious solution in 2017 is to use `List::UtilsBy::nsort_by`.

Comment: @Schwern can you post your opinion on comment above? Tnx.

Answer (score 3):

If the numbers are really important, you might want to read them specifically after file name, with error reporting about missing files:

```
my @nums = 1 .. 1500;  # or whatever the highest is

for my $num (@nums) {
    my $file = "Temp$num.csv";
    unless (-e $file) {
        warn "Missing file: $file";
        next;
    }
    ...
    # proceed as normal
}
```

If you need a file count, you can simply use your old glob:

```
my @files = <Temp*.csv>;
my $count = @files;       # get the size of the array
my @nums = 1 .. $count;
```

On the other hand, if you control the process that prints the files, you might select a format that will automatically sort itself, such as:

```
temp00001.csv
temp00002.csv
temp00003.csv
temp00004.csv
...
temp00101.csv
```